# Using Python re.search to find range of numbers

Tags: python, range

I am trying to find a range of numbers within a string. The different ranges are listed below. How can I search a specific range of number?

Ensure the first number is between [1, 17], the second between [1, 37], etc.

```
import re   
Test1 = "This is a test 5-9-81-15"

A1 = range(1, 17)
A2 = range(1, 37)
A3 = range(76, 89)
A4 = range(13, 27)

x = re.search("{0}-{1}-{2}-{3}".format(A1, A2, A3, A4), Test1) 

if x: 
    print ("Match")
else:
    print ("No Match")
```

Comment: What is your expected output for this code?

Comment: He wants a validation parse, to ensure the first number is between [1, 17], the second between [1, 37], etc. So he would want it report a match for this example. At least, that's my guess.

Comment: Regular expressions are unlikely to be a good tool for this job. Better: use a regular expression just to split out the number parts, convert them to integers with `int()`, and test their values using ordinary Python code.

Comment: Regex is not good for determining if a number is in a range.  Parse the string to find the numbers (using either regex or splitting it appropriately), and then check each number against the ranges.

Comment: @Prashant is right for what I am trying to look for

Comment: Rather than commenting he's right, you should edit your question to clearly reflect what you are asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can get a string of just the numbers, here is how you might check to see if it fits your requirement:

```
>>> s = "5-9-81-15"          # String to parse
>>> lb = [1, 1, 76, 13]      # List of lower bounds
>>> ub = [17, 37, 89, 27]    # List of upper bounds

>>> vals = [int(x) for x in s.split('-')]   # vals contains [5, 9, 81, 15]

>>> all(x > L and x < U for x, L, U in zip(vals, lb, ub))    # does the check
True
```

An example that fails:

```
>>> s = "5-9-90-15"    # fails with the third number
>>> vals = [int(x) for x in s.split('-')]
>>> all(x > L and x < U for x, L, U in zip(vals, lb, ub))
False
```

Regular expressions is the right tool if you need to extract the digit sequence from a larger string that has other text/characters in it.

Answer (score 0):

Regex is all about matching characters. It doesn't understand numbers, dates, or anything else.

Although it's sometimes possible to build a regex to match, say, a number within a range, it can get very long-winded and messy.

The best solution is to try to find possible matches that *resemble* what you're looking for and then use some other method to check whether each actually *is* what you're looking for.